# how to calculate the Flops of conv2d.init about pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

```
class Conv2d_init(nn.Conv2d):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode="zeros"):
        super(Conv2d_init, self).__init__(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation, groups, bias, padding_mode)

    def reset_parameters(self):
        init.xavier_normal_(self.weight)
        if self.bias is not None:
            fan_in, _ = init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(self.weight)
            bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_in)
            init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)
```

```
class SegDecNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device, input_width, input_height, input_channels):
        super(SegDecNet, self).__init__()
        self.vo=Conv2d_init(in_channels=3, out_channels=256,kernel_size=5, padding=2, bias=False)
        self.vo2=Conv2d_init(in_channels=256, out_channels=512,kernel_size=5, padding=2, bias=False)
        #self.vo=nn.Conv2d(3,256,kernel_size=5,stride=1,padding=2)
        #self.vo2=nn.Conv2d(256,512,kernel_size=5,stride=1,padding=2)
    def forward(self, input):
        x=self.vo(input)
        x=self.vo2(x)
        return x
```

from torch import nn as nn
import torch
from torch.nn import init
from ptflops import get_model_complexity_info

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = SegDecNet(1,640,232,3)
    model = model.cuda(0)
    input= torch.rand(1, 3, 640, 232 ).cuda(0)
    model_name="aaa"
    flops, params = get_model_complexity_info(model, (3,640,232),as_strings=True,print_per_layer_stat=True)
    print("%s |%s |%s" % (model_name,flops,params))
    '''time_sum_all=0
```

```
when i use the above code,i found use conv2d.init,the Flops is zero.use nn.conv2d Flops is 500 GMac.
```

how do i calculate the Flops of conv2d.init, or the Flops is zero is true?